# My follower turned invisible, how can I fix it?

Tags: diablo-iii

After a long lag spike, my follower (scoundrel) is now invisible. I can see him shoot and hear him speak and even see his health bar appear when he is wounded, but the model itself is invisible on the screen and does not appear in the minimap. How can I fix it?

Screenshot (click for full size):

[image: Screenshot that does not show the Scoundrel's toon but does show the portrait in the upper left corner as well as arrows firing from nowhere.]

Comment: Nice issue you have there, have you tried reporting this to Blizzard? This looks more like a bug than something they've intended. Glad to hear zoning fixes it, that would have been my suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tried moving about and tried switching his items, but at the end the only thing that worked was area transition (went down a floor) - it fixed it.